# Can't perform arithmetic operations on an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to find the sum of the integers in an ArrayList, however I am having issues with data types.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < InputArray.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + InputArray.get(i)
    }
```

However this is giving me the error:

```
error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
```

I have also tried:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < InputArray.size(); i++) {
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(InputArray.get(i));
    sum = sum + foo;
}
```

However this is giving me the error:

```
error: no suitable method found for parseInt(object)
```

The ArrayList contains integers only.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What's the type of your `InputArray` variable?

Comment: ArrayList InputArray = new ArrayList(); is what I declared it as.

Comment: Use generics!  If `InputArray` contains `Integer` objects, then it should be written `ArrayList<Integer> inputArray = new ArrayList<Integer>()`.

Comment: Integers, the user is promped to enter integers one by one and they are added to the arraylist with InputArray.add(input.nextLine());

Comment: You could try `Integer.parseInt(InputArray.get(i).toString())` depending on the object type.

Comment: If there are only ints in your list, you should do:  `ArrayList<Integer> InputArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: Ah, turns out the integers are being stored as strings. I used Integer.parseInt( input.nextLine() ) to convert them to integers and now it seems to be working.

Comment: Then use `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` if using Java 7, otherwise use `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` but **stop** using raw collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ArrayList InputArray = new ArrayList(); is what I declared it as

Elements of collections that use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) need to be cast to access the methods of the reference types. Generics were introduced to avoid this. Replace

```
ArrayList InputArray = new ArrayList();
```

with

```
List<Integer> inputArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//If your list should only Integers, there's no reason not to do this
ArrayList<Integer> InputArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Add some integers
InputArray.add(1);
InputArray.add(2);
InputArray.add(100);

//Create your sum variable
int sum = 0;

//You could use a foreach loop
for(int i : InputArray) {
  sum += i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the type of your ArrayList;

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    a.add(i);
}
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum = sum + a.get(i);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that the ArrayList is created the correct way with the desired type:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then you can make a loop:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++ 
{
sum += list.get(i);   
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Try this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code using an input array of strings as you should have strings as input from user (from input.nextLine):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sum {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    List<String> InputArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    InputArray.add("1");
    InputArray.add("2");

    int sum = 0;

    for(String element : InputArray) {
      sum += Integer.valueOf(element);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < InputArray.size(); i++) {
    int foo = Integer.parseInt(InputArray.get(i).toString());
    sum = sum + foo;
}
```

The reason it doesn't work is because you're trying to parse an `int` from something that's not a `String`.

By adding the `.toString()` method, you'll get around this.